# inline function and __thiscall __cdecl Bjarne String example

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, calling-convention

I have implementation of String class as in Bjarne "C++...". I want to have read() and other accessor functions inlined, so I marked them inline. It's ok, but defining hash function that do a read on a reference to class String in main file gives error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol char __thiscall String::read(int)const

why is this unresolved?

class String in String.h:

```
#include <string.h>

class String{
    struct Srep{  // representation
        char* s; // pointer to elements
        int sz;  // number of characters
        int n;   // reference counter
        Srep(int nsz, const char* p){
            n=1;
            sz=nsz;
            s=new char[sz+1]; // add space for terminator
            strcpy(s,p);
        }
        ~Srep(){delete[]s;}
        Srep* get_own_copy(){ // clone if necessary
            if(n==1)return this;
            n--;
            return new Srep(sz,s);
        }
        void assign(int nsz, const char* p){
            if(sz!=nsz){
                delete[]s;
                sz=nsz;
                s=new char[sz+1];
            }
            strcpy(s,p);
        }
    private: //prevent copying
        Srep(const Srep&);
        Srep& operator=(const Srep&);
    };
    Srep* rep;
public:
    class Cref{ // reference to char
        friend class String;
        String& s;
        int i;
        Cref(String& ss, int ii):s(ss), i(ii){}
    public:
        inline operator char(){                 // yield value
            return s.read(i);
        }
        inline void operator=(char c){              // change value
            s.write(i,c);
        }
    };
    class Range{};

    String();                       // x=""
    String(const char*);            // x="abnm'
    String(const String&);          // x=other_string
    String& operator=(const char*);
    String& operator=(const String&);
    ~String();
    // access operators
    void check(int i)const;
    inline char read(int i)const;
    void write(int i, char c);
    Cref operator[](int i);
    char operator[](int i)const;
    int size()const;
};
```

String.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"

String::String(){       // the empty string is the default value
    rep=new Srep(0,"");
}
String::String(const String& x){    // copy constructor
    x.rep->n++;
    rep=x.rep; // share representation
}
String::~String(){
    if(--rep->n==0)delete rep;
}
String& String::operator=(const String& x){ // copy assignment
    x.rep->n++; // protects against "st=st"
    if(--rep->n==0)delete rep;
    rep=x.rep;
    return *this;
}
// pseudo-copy operations taking const char* args are provided to allow
//string literals
String::String(const char* s){
    rep=new Srep(strlen(s),s);
}
String& String::operator=(const char* s){
    if(rep->n==1)   // recycle Srep
        rep->assign(strlen(s),s);
    else{           //use new Srep
        rep->n--;
        rep=new Srep(strlen(s),s);
    }
    return *this;
}
// access operators
inline void String::check(int i)const{
    if(i<0||rep->sz<=i)throw Range();
}
inline char String::read(int i)const{ // unchecked access to s
    return rep->s[i];
}
inline void String::write(int i, char c){
    rep=rep->get_own_copy();
    rep->s[i]=c;
}
inline String::Cref String::operator[](int i){
    check(i);
    return Cref(*this,i);
}
inline char String::operator[](int i)const{// checked access to s
    check(i);
    return rep->s[i];
}
inline int String::size()const{
    return rep->sz;
}
```

main file:

```
// Bjarne_exercise_string.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"

int hash(const String& s){
    //int h=s.read(0);
    //const int max=s.size();
    //for(int i=1;i<max;i++){
    //  h^=s.read(i)>>1; // unchecked access to s (1st take s[i], then rightshift, and then XOR h and this)
    //}
    //return h;
    return 4;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    String s1;
    String s2;
    String s3="s3";
    String s4("s4");
    String s5(s3);
    s5=s4;
    s3=s4;
    //int i=hash(s3);
    //i=hash(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you decide to just inline a few functions? `inline` in C++ does not mean "please optimize this", if that is what you think. The compiler is free to inline, or not inline, any function it likes. The `inline` keyword changes how a function is linked, so that multiple translation units can each have a definition of the same function.

Comment: it is not the topic, the question is why this inlined function is unresolved

Comment: has it perhaps occurred to you that there might be a connection between the linker error you are getting for reasons you don't understand, and your decision to insert a keyword you don't understand into your code? Unless this is a trick question, and you already know the answer, I suggest you be a bit more open to what people are telling you. It is just possible that the people commenting or answering your question *might know something that you don't*

Comment: An `inline` function will also be local to its compilation unit. That doesn't work well with defining it in a .cpp file. It works much better in a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have function inlined it should be defined in header.
If you really want inline functions move definitions to header or move them to body of the class and remove inline. 
To have mo linkage arrors remove inline specifier before `read`

Comment: no, really, try to move them to header.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-member-fns.html

Comment: I have moved it to the header file, yes, now it is OK

Answer (score 1):

Function's can't be inlined unless their bodies are available to the compiler at the call site.  Move all the inline functions into the header file.

As for your linker errors, did you remember to link with `String.obj`?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't got a `String::read()` function. Implement that, and you'll be golden [or at least a few steps closer!]

Comment: Ah, but not in your .h file, so when the compiler compiles the file that uses the inline function, it doesn't see it. Sorry that I didn't look in the "wrong file". It should be in the header file.

Comment: don't have to be sorry. I wouldn't ask if I had put this in the right place at the beginning.